# magneto 2.4.6 -p2 - category page filter is only working if we redirect back to catagory page after product selection

Tags: magento2.4.6

I am getting HTML tag on catagroy page if I apply filter and add any product to cart and again back to category page then this error occurs ob console I can see ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error  [image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems something whole page returning an Ajax request response appears on the page. Does this appear on all category pages by applying a filter or on any specific category?

Check if you are using any custom module that causes this issue. Which version of Magento 2 are you using?

Possible use cases:

- turn off the debug logs in cart function return back to the page.
- Run the compilation command: `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.
- Disable any external module related to cart.

Check for this event and see what action is performed in your code.

```
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="company_module_checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Vendor\Magento\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfter" />
</event>
```

Comment: Jyotishina .. issue is occurring on all category pages when we apply filter and redirect to product detail page and if we press back button for category page then we got this product response data on page 

I have checked and it is looking like elastic search  issue 

we are using magento - 2.4.6-p2 , PHP 8.1.1 ,
elastic search : "smile/elasticsuite": "2.11.3.2", "web200/magento-elasticsuite-ajax": "^1.0"

Comment: Jyotishina actually we are using opensearch with below setting 'catalog' => [
'search' => [
'engine' => 'elasticsuite',
'elasticsearch7_server_hostname' => 'http://127.0.0.1',
'elasticsearch7_server_port' => '9200',
'elasticsearch7_index_prefix' => 'magento2_dev'
]
],
'smile_elasticsuite_core_base_settings' => [
'es_client' => [
'servers' => 'opensearch:9200',
'indices_alias' => 'magento2_dev',
'enable_https_mode' => 0,
'http_auth_user' => '',
'http_auth_pwd' => '',
'enable_http_auth' => false
],

Comment: Did you turn off elasticsearch and check again if the issue is resolved?